# Hive Erro- FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am getting this error: **FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask** when I try to create a table in hive. I am new to this and stuck at this point.

Please help me find a solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set hive.metastore.schema.verification property in hive-site.xml to true, by default it is false.

For details see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool).

Comment: It is still the same. No change even after setting the property value to true.

Comment: Can you share the complete log, may be then we can have some solution. The one I mentioned worked fine for me.